# JavaFX imports and extends application not getting recognized

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm having an issue with my JavaFX imports and the extends application portion of my main method.
I've tried cycling through all the SDK and programming level features on my IntelliJ and still no luck

[Screenshot of the issue on IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgLVq.jpg)

Sorry for the low-quality image but any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the javafx library is not added to your classpath. This can be done by adding the folloging to your VM options:

```
--module-path [path\to\your\javafx\home\lib] --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH
```

where `[path\to\your\javafx\home\lib]` must point to the location where you downloaded javafx as it does not come with the jdk as of version 11: [download](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)

You can also add it as an external library in IntelliJ within the module settings (Dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

If you hover the mouse over one of the red marks on the right-hand size, it should tell you what's wrong with the import. It seems that the IDE is complaining about all your javafx imports, but the other java imports are fine, so my guess is that you are using a JDK version that does not include JavaFX. If that is the case, you need to add it as an extrernal library to your project.
To do that, click on File->Project Structure, then select Libraries, click on the "+" icon, browse to the "lib" sub-folder of the JavaFX SDK folder, and add it.